# Server synchronisation service is not working correctly

Tags: windows-users

I am getting the below error in *WSUS server*.

Please someone help in this regards.

> Server synchronization service is not working correctly. This might be
>   because of configuration issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run this command on CMD   wsusutil.exe checkhealth, after this will create a eventlog. In the eventlog it should show "WSUS configured correctly"
2. Run clean-up job.